# http://domain.com/category?page=2 or higher pages not working. Stays on home category or page1

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using .htaccess redirects to get unique urls for my site. Problem now is I can't for the life of me get category pages higher than page 1 to show.

Below is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|xml|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond%{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?_route_=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
Ensure we are using HTTPS version of the site.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

If the `QSA` directive does not work you can try this instead:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|xml|css)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1&%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?_route_=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
# Ensure we are using HTTPS version of the site.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```